# Wait for two observables (incl. failed one) before rendering template

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-observable, rxjs-observables

I have two Observables. The rendering of the template should only start when **BOTH** Observables are completed or failed:

- Observable 1 completes and Observable 2 completes or
- Observable 1 completes, but Observable 2 fails
- When Observable 1 fails Observable 2 is not important because the template won't be rendered completely then

(Ignore the `<any>` type, it's only for simplification here)

Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  obs1$ = new Subject<any>();
  obs2$ = new Subject<any>();

  isLoading = true;
  isObs1Error: boolean;
  isObs2Error: boolean;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeDataRetrieval();
  }

  initializeDataRetrieval() {
    this.obs1$ = this.obs1Method();
    this.obs1$.subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.isObs1Error = false;
      this.obs1 = response;

      this.obs2$ = this.obs2Method();
      this.obs2$.subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.isObs2Error = false;
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.obs2 = response;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
    });
  }

  private obs1Method(): any {
    return this.obs1Service
      .getStuff()
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          this.isError = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          return EMPTY;
        })
      );
  }

  private obs2Method(): any {
    return this.obs2Service
      .getStuff()
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          this.isObs2Error = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          return EMPTY;
        })
      );
  }

  canDisplayContent(): boolean {
    return !this.isLoading && !this.isObs1Error;
  }
```

Template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
  <app-loading-indicator></app-loading-indicator>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="isObs1Error">
  <div class="error">
    This Obs1 stuff could not be loaded currently
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="canDisplayContent()">
  <div class="error" *ngIf="isObs2Error">
    Technical error
  </div>
  More content here which is shown when at least Obs1 doesn't had an error
</div>
```

So basically:

- I wanna wait with template rendering until both Observables are done and display a loading indicator during the time
- When there is an error with Obs1 then show a message
- When there is an error with Obs2 then render the 3rd `ng-container` with the Obs2 error message

I'm sure the TS code can be simplified by the usage of ... which RxJS operator? Although reading through [RxJS Operators for Dummies: forkJoin, zip, combineLatest, withLatestFrom](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom) I'm not sure if any of these fits. As far as I understood e.g. `combineLatest` only succeeds when both streams complete successfully ...

Any hint is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider to use `forkJoin` for this case.

The code would look like this

```
forkJoin(this.obs1Method(), this.obs2Method()).subscribe(
   ({resp1, resp2}) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.obs2 = resp1;
        this.obs2 = resp2;
        this.cdr.detectChanges()
   }
)
```

You would have probably also to change slightly the `obsxMethod`s adding a `tap` to set the error properties to false in case of successful retrieval of data and remove the settings which are performed within the `subscribe`, like this

```
private obs1Method(): any {
    return this.obs1Service
      .getStuff()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.isError = false),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isError = true;
          return EMPTY;
        })
      );
  }

  private obs2Method(): any {
    return this.obs2Service
      .getStuff()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.isObs2Error = false),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isObs2Error = true;
          return EMPTY;
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, currently observing ;) your idea. Found out: Due to a deprecation-warning for `forkJoin` I need to wrap both Observables in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
const decorateObservable = (obs$, key) => obs$.pipe(
  mapTo(false), // `false` -> no error
  catchError(() => of(true)), // `true` -> error found
  map(value => ({ key, value })) // Identification
)

const base$ = merge(
  decorateObservable(obs1$, 'obs1'),
  decorateObservable(obs2$, 'obs2'),
).pipe(
  // When the source is unsubscribed(`error`/`complete`),
  finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
  share(),
)

const obs1Displayed$ = base$.pipe(
  filter(o => o.key === 'obs1'),
  map(o => o.value),
)

const obs2Displayed$ = base$.pipe(
  filter(o => o.key === 'obs2'),
  map(o => o.value),
)
```

The `share()` operator is used here because subscribing multiple times to the source is not desired.

In this case, you'd be subscribing **twice**(in the template), because both *displayed* observables derive from the same base. What `share` does it to **multicast** the data producer.

`share` is the same as `pipe(multicast(() => new Subject()), refCount())`. `refCount` indicates that the producer will be *invoked* as soon as the first subscriber comes in.

Put differently, the data consumer sort of decides when the producer should start its logic.

Note that I've assumed that `obs1$` and `obs2$` are producing values asynchronously.

Essentially, it's almost the same as doing:

```js
const s  = new Subject();

// The subscriptions happen inside the template
s.pipe(filter(o => o.key === 'obs1', ...).subscribe(observer1)
s.pipe(filter(o => o.key === 'obs2', ...).subscribe(observer2)

// And later on...
s.next({ key: 'obs1', value: false }) // `obs1$` emitted
```

And here's the template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
  <app-loading-indicator></app-loading-indicator>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="obs1Displayed$ | async">
  <div class="error">
    This Obs1 stuff could not be loaded currently
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="obs2Displayed$ | async">
  <div class="error">
    Technical error
  </div>
  More content here which is shown when at least Obs1 doesn't had an error
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this inspiring different appraoch.